Вычисли с помощью C++ значения функции f от двух переменных a и b

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double f(double a, double b) {
    double part1 = pow(2 * a + b + atan(a + sqrt(b)), 2);
    double part2 = sqrt(pow(sin((2 * a + b) / M_PI), 2) + pow(a + sqrt(b), 2));
    double part3 = pow(2 * a + b, 2) + exp(a + sqrt(b));
    double part4 = 2 * a + b + pow(tan((a * a + b + atan(a + 2 * b)) / M_PI), 2);
    double part5 = sqrt(pow(sin((a * a + b) / M_PI), 2) + pow(a + 2 * b, 2));
    double part6 = pow(a * a + b, 2) + exp(a + 2 * b);

    return (part1 * part2) / (part3 * part4 * part5 / part6);
}

int main() {
    double a, b;

    cout << "Введите значения a и b: ";
    cin >> a >> b;

    cout << "f(" << a << ", " << b << ") = " << f(a, b) << endl;

    return 0;
}


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Как минимум косяк: тригонометрия в программе вычисляется от радианов, а как задано у вас - знают "не только лишь все". Но судя по коду, все в градусах. Так что не правильно.

Не все "part" у вас найдены и вычисляется от них что попало.

При всем уважении :), я не вижу в вычислении суммы двух больших частей...

@Ingvar И как вы по коду судите, что вычисления в градусах? :) Другое дело, что у ТС код в принципе не соответствует заданию. Alexander, ну вот, например, где у вас на картинке тангенс от a^2+b+арктангенс?

@Harry, если честно - это самый большой косяк в математике - складывать мухи и котлеты, сорри  складывать разноплановые величины. А большинство математических выражений (формул) вычисляются именно в градусах, если брать их как есть из книг и учебников. Короче, пусть ТС уточнит задание.

@Harry, составить программу, вычисляющую значения функции f от двух переменных a и b

Начну издалека, как один профессор медицины студентам рассказывал, что врач должен быть внимательным и не брезгливым. Вот, например, как врач в средние века определял сахар в моче... Тут профессор окунает палец в баночку с мочой и облизывает. Потом предлагает повторить студентам. Все мнутся, наконец, один смельчак повторяет действия профессора.
— Браво, коллега! Отсутствие брезгливости вы отлично продемонстрировали, но вот со внимательностью у вас пока проблемы... Вы не обратили внимания, что я окунал в мочу указательный палец, а облизал средний...
Вам тоже недостает внимательности...
double f(double a, double b)
{
    double a_sq_b = a + sqrt(b);
    double a_p_2b = a + 2*b;
    double a2_p_b = 2*a + b;
    double aa_p_b = a*a + b;
    double p1 = sq(a2_p_b+atan(a_sq_b))*sqrt(sq(sin(a2_p_b/M_PI))+sq(a_sq_b));
    double q1 = (sq(a2_p_b)+exp(a_sq_b))*sq(a2_p_b+sq(tan(a_sq_b/M_PI)));
    double p2 = sq(aa_p_b+atan(a_p_2b))*sqrt(sq(sin(aa_p_b/M_PI))+sq(a_p_2b));
    double q2 = (sq(aa_p_b)+exp(a_p_2b))*sq(aa_p_b+sq(tan(a_p_2b/M_PI)));
    return p1/q1 + p2/q2;
}


Спасибо за помощь, но ответ все равно не корректные выдает, не такие, как в задании указанны

Тригонометрические функции принимают на вход РАДИАНЫ ни у автора ни у отвечающего нет преобразования из градусов в радианы. Вы уверены в том, что параметры задаются сразу в радианах? Топикстартер не уточнил этот момент

Ну вот зачем чушь нести? https://bit.ly/4gsOkQP - сами смотрите, все нормально считает (это к Alexander). Все, как в задании! И, кстати, раз считает правильно - значит, все нормально, считать надо в радианах (это к @Ingvar). Блин, что за люди пошли... не проверив, сразу в бутылку лезть... Поневоле жалеешь, что помогаешь.
